# How to create a table for liking post by user in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three tables for blog posts:

- `Post` table for posts properties like `PostID`, `Title` and etc.
- `User` table for authors properties like `UserID` and etc.
- `PostLike` table including of two columns such as `PostID` and `UserID` an they are foreign key columns. this table stores users like of posts. In fact when a user liking a post, one record is inserting in this table.

My code is:

```
    public partial class Post
      {
        public Post()
             {
             }
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(150)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
      }

    public partial class User
      {
        public User()
            {
              Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
            }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required,StringLength(50)]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
      }

    public partial class PostLike
     {
        public PostLike()
           {
             Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
             Users = new HashSet<User>();
           }

         [Key,Column(Order = 0),ForeignKey("Posts")]
         public int PostID { get; set; }
         [Key, Column(Order = 1),ForeignKey("Users")]
         public int UserID { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

     }
```

But when the database is creating, `PostLike` table has not any foreign key and `User` table has two foreign keys such as `PostLike_PostID` and `PostLike_UserID`. It is necessary to point that `Post` table has not those foreign keys.
Is it possible to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each record in your PostLike record will have only one Post and one User. So you do not need the collection type.

```
public class PostLike
{
  public int Id { set; get; }
  public int PostID { get; set; }
  public int UserID { get; set; }

  public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now to prevent the "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error, you just need to disable cascading delete. You can do that in the `OnModelCreating` method of your data context class.

```
public class YourDataContex : DbContext()
{    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
       modelBuilder.Entity<PostLike>()
       .HasRequired(c => c.User)
       .WithMany()
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { set; get; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { set; get; }
    public DbSet<PostLike> PostLikes { set; get; }
}
```

This will create the PostLikes table with 3 columns `Id`, `PostID`(FK) and `UserID`(FK)

Comment: Thanks so much, It worked. Is `Id` column necessary? Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: If we add attribute `[Key, Column(Order = 1)]` and `[Key, Column(Order = 2)]` to `PostID` and `UserID`, it is possible to remove `Id` column.

Comment: @msitworld don't know if it's changed, but the general opinion (mainly expressed by Julie Lerman, who is a known EF expert) was that you should avoid joining tables that don't have any columns other than the foreign keys. She recommended always including the ID column, as EF could have problems otherwise.